# oracle - case statement and group by

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi – I need your assistance with below query. I’m trying to run the below query below to group by but I get the following error:

> ORA-00904:” SALES_ID_CO”:invalid identifier

Can you please help with this? Many Thanks.

```
Select
count(1),
sales_date,
CASE 
WHEN sales_id like '1%'
THEN substr(sales_id,2,6)
WHEN sales_id  like '3%'
THEN substr(sales_id ,2,6)
WHEN sales_id  like '4%'
THEN substr(sales_id ,2,6)
WHEN sales_id  like '5%'
THEN substr(sales_id ,2,6)
WHEN sales_id  like '9%'
THEN substr(sales_id ,1,6)
WHEN sales_id  like '70%' OR sales_id  like '90%' OR sales_id  like '31%'
THEN substr(sales_id ,2,6)
END AS SALES_ID_CO,

case
WHEN sales_branch like '10%' AND sales_code<> '678 '
THEN substr(sales_branch,2,6)
WHEN sales_branch like '200%' AND sales_code<> '678 '
THEN substr(sales_branch,2,6)
WHEN sales_branch like '300%' AND sales_code<> '678 '
THEN substr(sales_branch,2,6)
WHEN sales_branch like '456%' AND sales_code<> '678 '
THEN substr(sales_branch,2,6)
END AS SALES_BRANCH

from tbl_sales_cde

where sales_country IN (‘USA’,’ASIA’,’EU’) 
group by SALES_ID_CO, SALES_BRANCH,SALES_DATE
```

Comment: You've missed out a `THEN` clause on the final `WHEN` of the first `CASE` statement. You've also missed out all the `LIKE` statements from the second `CASE` statement.

Comment: `CASE` clause is executed sequentially. Therefore, you will never have `sales_id  like '90%'` because you have `sales_id  like '9%'` before which will match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support column aliases in the `group by` clause.  Use a subquery:

```
SELECT SALES_ID_CO, SALES_BRANCH,SALES_DATE, COUNT(*)
FROM (Select sales_date,
             (CASE  WHEN sales_id like '1%'
                    THEN substr(sales_id,2,6)
                    WHEN sales_id  like '3%'
                    THEN substr(sales_id ,2,6)
                    WHEN sales_id  like '4%'
                    THEN substr(sales_id ,2,6)
                    WHEN sales_id  like '5%'
                    THEN substr(sales_id ,2,6)
                    WHEN sales_id  like '9%'
                    THEN substr(sales_id ,1,6)
                    WHEN sales_id  like '70%' OR sales_id  like '90%' OR sales_id  like '31%'
               END) AS SALES_ID_CO,
              (case WHEN sales_branchlike '10%' AND sales_code<> '678 '
                    THEN substr(sales_branch,2,6)
                    WHEN sales_branchlike '200%' AND sales_code<> '678 '
                    THEN substr(sales_branch,2,6)
                    WHEN sales_branchlike '300%' AND sales_code<> '678 '
                    THEN substr(sales_branch,2,6)
                    WHEN sales_branchlike '456%' AND sales_code<> '678 '
                    THEN substr(sales_branch,2,6)
                END) AS SALES_BRANCH
       from tbl_sales_cde
       where sales_country IN ('USA', 'ASIA', 'EU') 
      ) s
group by SALES_ID_CO, SALES_BRANCH,SALES_DATE;
```

Note:  You also had curly single quotes in the `where` clause, but that might be a copying issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SALES_ID_CO,
       SALES_BRANCH,
       SALES_DATE,
       count(1)
FROM   (
  SELECT sales_date,
         CASE
         WHEN sales_id  LIKE '70%'
         OR   sales_id  LIKE '90%'
         OR   sales_id  LIKE '31%'
         OR   SUBSTR( sales_id, 1, 1 ) IN ( '1', '3', '4', '5' )
           THEN substr(sales_id,2,6)
         WHEN sales_id  LIKE '9%'
           THEN substr(sales_id ,1,6)
         END AS SALES_ID_CO,
         CASE
         WHEN sales_code<> '678 '
         AND  (
              sales_branch LIKE '10%'
           OR sales_branch LIKE '200%'
           OR sales_branch LIKE '300%'
           OR sales_branch LIKE '456%'
         )
           THEN substr(sales_branch,2,6)
         END AS SALES_BRANCH
  from   tbl_sales_cde
  where  sales_country IN ('USA','ASIA','EU')
)
group by SALES_ID_CO, SALES_BRANCH,SALES_DATE
```